# Call to web api blocked by CORS policy even though .net webapi allows all methods

Tags: .net, axios, cors, preflight

UPDATE 2:
SOLVED: See my answer below.

UPDATE 1:
Even if I hard code the program.cs in my webapi to ALWAYS set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header the header is NOT set when calling the api with an OPTIONS/POST request.

So to rule out that there is some firewall "outside" of the server hosting the webapi when calling it I opened a remote desktop to the server and browse my web application locally. This should make the scenario "the same" as when I'm on my development machine. Unfortunately exactly the same thing happens. All types of calls except GET are "blocked by cors policy". This is driving me crazy, could it be any configuration on the web site that blocks some calls?

See hardcoded headers below that still don't help even though when running both my webapp and webapi on my development machine it works just fine:

```
 app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
 {    
   var org = ctx.Request.Headers["Origin"];
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(org) && allowedOrigins.Contains(org))
   {
     ctx.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", org);
   }

   ctx.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

   if (HttpMethods.IsOptions(ctx.Request.Method))
   {
     ctx.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH");
     ctx.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
     await ctx.Response.CompleteAsync();
     return;
   }

   await next();
  });
```

I thought I understood how to configure cors for a .net framework webapi but I can't figure out this one.

I have a vue/vuetify website and a .net framework 8 webapi website running on the same server. Of course on my development computer there are errors as everything always works fine on the machines of developers.

However, when installing the websites on our test-server we get an error that seems to be cors-related. But all the "GET" calls work fine but no POST/PATCH requests work. The error logged in the console of Chrome is the following:

***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://crmappdev1:8050/api/generic/getAnyServiceCarisma' from origin 'https://crmappdev1:8051' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

When setting up CORS in my webapi I've been as least restricive as possible, allowing all methods and headers but still no success. The only difference I've noticed is that if I DON'T specify "AllowAnyMethod" then all calls fail but if I either say ".AllowAnyMethod" or specify which methods to allow then the "GET" start working but all other types fail. I've found a number of articles describing the order of how to chain the setup in the Program.cs for the webapi and I've tried everything but there is apparently something I'm missing. I would be most grateful for any suggestions to solve this.

The result of the POST in chrome network tab, as you can see it says "Unauthorized" and "OPTIONS" when executing the POST request which I think is a hint but I can't figure out what to make of it:

[image: Result in chrome network tab]

The current version of my Program.cs is below. Works fine on my local development machine but not when installed on the server:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

 List<string> allowedOrigins = new List<string>
 {
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:8051",
    // DEV ENV
    "http://crmappdev1:8051",
    "https://crmappdev1:8051"        
};

builder.Services.AddCors(
    options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins.ToArray())
            //.AllowAnyMethod()
            //.WithMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            //.AllowAnyHeader()
            //.AllowCredentials()
            ;
        }
);
    });

builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddNewtonsoftJson();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.UseCors(
builder =>
{
    builder
    .WithOrigins(allowedOrigins.ToArray())
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH")
    //.AllowAnyMethod()
    ;
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading "everything" about CORS and how to configure a WebApi to allow CORS under certain conditions I started thinking that maybe it was a problem on IIS level.

So after finding this thread:
[Ajax CORS Request with http 401 in preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735921/ajax-cors-request-with-http-401-in-preflight)
I configured the web site for my WebAPI to allow "Anonymous Authentication" which finally made the OPTIONS request pass without the "401 Unauthorized". To further enhance security I added the "Authorization Rule" to apply to "All anonymous users" and apply specifically for the "OPTIONS" verb.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your error.

> origin 'https://crmappdev1.xxx.xxx.se:8051' has been blocked by CORS policy

You need to add `https://crmappdev1.xxx.xxx.se:8051` as an allowed origin

Comment: Hi, I put "xxx.xxx" instead of the real domain name to not give away information. Anyhow, I have tried adding "https://crmappdev1.xxx.xxx.se:8051" in the allowed origins now but still get the same error. To further clarify: I've now added both "https://crmappdev1:8051" AND "https://crmappdev1.xxx.xxx.se:8051" to allowedOrigins but still I get the same error :(

Comment: I understand what you did but I think you may have caught onto the idea.   CORS requires the *exact* hostname *and* protocol (so http or https, and those must match too).  I'm going to  leave the answer because it was a requirement you needed regardless.  If you're still having errors, a 401 unauthorized is also suspicious.  It makes me wonder if there's some authentication ahead of it in the way, such as if you were using an API gateway in front of the actual API

Comment: I agree it's weird with the 401. When my vue-page loads it makes a bunch of calls to my api which in turn fetch data from a System that requires NTLM authentication. Since all the calls made with GET actually fetches data from the system and displays it correctly it beats me why the POST/PATCH get the 401... I appreciate the answer still, I guess I'm gonna have to dig deep into this one :)