# When Creating A REST Endpoint Backend, Should Options NOT Be Secured?

Tags: rest, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a microservice that exposes GET and POST requests for clients to call. I am setting this up in AWS Api Gateway, but I think my general question applies to any hosting platform.

I built the endpoint, deployed it to AWS Lambda, and exposed it as endpoints via Api Gateway. I then try to call to it from the browser like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url:        options.url,
            dataType:   'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            type:       "POST",
            x-api-key:  "asdfasdfasdfadf_MY_KEY_adsfadsfasdf",
            data:       options.params,
            success:    doSuccessStuff
            error:      doErrorStuff
        });
```

Everything seems to work fine when I check "API Key Required" for the GET and POST request but leave it unchecked for OPTIONS.

However, when I check "Api key required" for *Options* then I get a 403 error when calling to it.

[image]
[image]

So that leads me to wonder, **is this the best practice- to have all your resources except Options be guarded by an Api Key**? And is this true as well for "Authorization" and "Request Validator"?

[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818926/2190251