# Origin null in IE 11. CORS is not working unless from localhost

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors, same-origin-policy, internet-explorer-11

I am using an xhr to make a cross domain POST request to a service that is hosted on another server. I have enabled CORS by setting the required headers on the server's IIS, viz. **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** as '*' and **Acces-Control-Allow-Headers** as 'content-type, x-request-with', etc.

This xhr is part of the script for a site (say X).

1. When X is hosted on my machine (IIS), I am able to make the CORS request when I access the site as http: //localhost/X. Whereas when I browse to http: //my-machine-name/X, I get the **Access Denied** error (as observed from IE's debugger).
2. When X is hosted on another server and when I access X from my machine, I get the **Access Denied** error once again.

Also note the following points:

1. From Chrome, CORS is working properly. I can see the OPTIONS request at first from fiddler. From IE11 however, the request is not even sent.
2. **Access data sources across domains** is set to **Disable** on IE 11. I do not want to change that setting.
3. When I disabled the option (from point 2), I noticed that the requests are being sent with no ORIGIN header by IE 11. From localhost however, the ORIGIN is set as 'http //localhost'. Chrome sets the ORIGIN as 'my-machine-name' even when I browse to X using http: //my-machine-name/X.
4. I have also tried using an ajax post request. I get the same error in IE 11 when I use that as well.

Please help me out here. I want to know why IE 11 is not setting the ORIGIN header in the cases mentioned, as I believe that to be the reason why CORS isn't working.

Comment: Don't suppose you ever solved this did you? Just hit something similar and trying to find information about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the preflight OPTIONS request of an authenticated CORS request work in Chrome but not Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734031/why-does-the-preflight-options-request-of-an-authenticated-cors-request-work-in)