# Can't manage to make CORS request working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, cors

I'm trying to get some data from a webservice on a different domain, and I'm experiencing some CORS issue.

I have something like this in my controller :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url : 'http://somewebserviceapi.com?idAppli=' + appId, headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ='}}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function() {
            console.log("An error occured");
        });
```

And I'm getting the following errors :

> OPTIONS http://somewebserviceapi.com?idLangue=1&idAppli=2153 b @ angular.js:9866n @ angular.js:9667$get.f @ angular.js:9383(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13248$get.n.$eval @ angular.js:14466$get.n.$digest @ angular.js:14282$get.n.$apply @ angular.js:14571showApplication @ viewerController.js:825handleApplications @ svgManipulation.js:15SvgPanZoom.handleMouseUp @ svg-pan-zoom.js:1195SvgPanZoom.setupHandlers.eventListeners.mouseup @ svg-pan-zoom.js:829

and

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://somewebserviceapi.com?idLangue=1&idAppli=2153 . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Now the headers :

When it is called from my controller : (It seems no authentification is made)

(Response)

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 14:33:09 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
                  Basic realm="AD-ITS.SOME-COMPANY.COM"
```

(Request)

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Methods: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: somewebserviceapi.com
Origin: http://localhost:63342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

When I go myself to the url :

(Response)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 394
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 15:21:08 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache
```

(Request)

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=89C1EC542BCBC42421C6207767EF8FA1
Host:  http://somewebserviceapi.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

And on Chrome, additionally to the response and request header there is a general header visible :
In this header, I have :

From my controller request : `Request Method:OPTIONS`

When i go the URL myself : `Request Method:GET`

Apparently, the `OPTIONS` method is the way CORS handle some things, but do I need to add OPTIONS Method somewhere ?

Server side, I do have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` line, so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Launch a server from your command line using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your project's directory. Or just find any one of the answers already on Stack Overflow... it seems this same question gets asked every day.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't have the hand on the server, I requested to add the CORS support, which has been added, but maybe something is still missing.

Comment: Launch _your_ app with this command. The server you are pinging is doing the right thing.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Python and I don't even have it installed (I'm on windows btw).
However I also tried to run the app on a http-server using `http-server -a localhost` and accessing it through `http://localhost:8080/` and I have the same errors, the used method still is `OPTIONS`

Answer (score 0):

This is classic CORS issue, when you make a call from JS and CORS logic is applied then first call that will be made is `OPTIONS` which should return

`200 OK` with empty response (not sure if it really has to be empty)

and headers:

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

when the `OPTIONS` is correctly configured then another call will be made provided that method can be found in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT`

although `OPTIONS` have to be added to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

Comment: How the `OPTIONS` should be configured ?

If I add `OPTIONS` to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, a second call will be made with the proper `GET` method and taht's it ?

Comment: Correct, `OPTIONS` is there to confirm which methods can be used, i.e. you want only `DELETE` method on certain api endpoint then any other attempt will fail. So just add `OPTIONS` to allowed methods and configure server to response with `success` for those calls

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is related to the preflight request (the OPTIONS request). Please take a look at this SO question [Why does the preflight OPTIONS request of an authenticated CORS request work in Chrome but not Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734031/why-does-the-preflight-options-request-of-an-authenticated-cors-request-work-in):

> How can I get the OPTIONS request to send and respond consistently?
>
> Simply have the server (API in this example) respond to OPTIONS
>   requests without requiring authentication.
>
> Kinvey did a good job expanding on this while also linking to an issue
>   of the Twitter API outlining the catch-22 problem of this exact
>   scenario interestingly a couple weeks before any of the browser issues
>   were filed.

And see if it works for you. (Also, since this seems to be also a browser-related issue, please check on different browser and see what happens)