# Pass in auth credentials when initializing JS Swagger client?

Tags: javascript, swagger-2.0

In JS, we normally pass in credentials in as it's being created but Swagger's documentation only shows how to do this after the client object has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just create an authorizations object with key names that align to the names in the `securityDefinitions` and pass it to the constructor.  Assuming a securityDefinition of:

```
"securityDefinitions" : {
  "sec_def_entry" : {
    "type" : "apiKey",
    "name" : "entry_name",
    "in" : "header"
  }
}
```

The code would look something like the following:

```
SwaggerClient = require('swagger-client'); //node
SwaggerClient = window.SwaggerClient;  //browser

var auths = {
  sec_def_entry : new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("entry_name", "special-key","header")
};


var client = new SwaggerClient({
  "url": 'https://example.com/swagger.json',
  authorizations: auths
})
```

Note, however, that this will cause Swagger to pass the credential information when retrieving the spec from the server.  This can cause issues if you have basic authorization turned on as basic-auth triggers an options preflight (costing an additional round-trip and [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734031/why-does-the-preflight-options-request-of-an-authenticated-cors-request-work-in) setting the server to respond with a 200 respons to all options requests) and [disallows wildcard origin in CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i).

Comment: Not really related, but your answer helped me to map actual arguments and swagger's definition: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/pull/911