# XMLHttpRequest cannot load .... Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Below is my service call where I am trying to do a basic auth. I have checked multiple blogs could not find the solution for this.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue as I am getting below error:

> **XMLHttpRequest cannot load**
>
> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

I could not find the basic auth in the network tab in developer options also.

```
function() {
    "use strict";
    var APIservice = function($http, $base64) {
        var getDetails = function(postData) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*";
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS";
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With";
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = undefined;
            console.log($http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization);
            //console.log($http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization);
            return $http.get('http://52.74.68.202:8080/rest/v1/step/all')
                .then(function(response, headers, config) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response;
                });
        };
        return {
            getDetails: getDetails
        }
    }
    var module = angular.module('expframework');
    module.factory("APIservice", APIservice);
    module.run(['$http', '$base64', function($http, $base64) {
        var authdata = $base64.encode('test:test');
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;
    }]);
    module.config(['$httpProvider', '$base64', function($httpProvider, $base64) {
        var authdata = $base64.encode('test:test');
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata;
    }])
}();
```

It is working in Safari and emulators but not working in Chrome and Firefox

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CORS headers mustn't be set by browsers but by servers: browsers will then first send an OPTIONS request to known if actual request is authorized. What kind of server is listening on http://52.74.68.202:8080/rest? Looks like a Tomcat one?

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled on your server? You need to let the OPTIONS preflight request to have access.

Comment: @sp00m - yes it is Tomcat and below is the response headers                                       Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization,Content-Type,X-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Message
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 12 Jul 2016 10:34:14 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="IntApp-Basic"

Comment: @DanielHigueras - please check my above comment. all the headers are added in my server

Comment: and this call is working in safari and emulators

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers should be removed from `$http.defaults.headers.common`. What headers are actually attached to requests? And a 401 error is weird: looks like the server is trying to authenticate OPTIONS requests. What COTS are you using for the authn? Could you try to exclude OPTIONS requests from the authn chain?

Comment: whatever above comment code is response headers below are the request headers and If I remove Access-Control-Allow also it is not working.                                          

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:52.74.68.202:8080

Comment: Could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15734032/1225328

Comment: @sp00m - I just hit the rest api using postman with options request here is what i got

**headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Authorization,Content-Type,X-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers →Message
Access-Control-Max-Age →3600
Allow →HEAD,GET,OPTIONS
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length →568
Content-Type →application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml;charset=UTF-8
Expires →0
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →DENY

Comment: body of postman option call
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"><doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.14 2014-12-11 07:22:06"/>  <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://52.74.68.202:8080/rest/v1/">
        <resource path="step/all">
            <method id="getAllSteps" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </response>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>

Comment: @sp00m - Thanks you are correct. Great help!

Thanks guys for your help. We are finally able to resolve it, It is because of server was trying to authenticate OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your server threw a 401, I guess it tried to authenticate the preflight request. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15734032/1225328:

> The [W3 spec for CORS preflight requests](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#preflight-request) clearly states that user credentials should be excluded.
>
> [...]
>
> Simply have the server (API in this example) respond to `OPTIONS` requests without requiring authentication.