# ES6 module loader in the browser ignores cookies

Tags: cookies, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In a typical module script

```
<script type="module" crossorigin="use-credentials">
    import {App} from './js/app.js';
    const app = new App();
    app.init();
</script>
```

Chrome, Safari and Edge have no issues loading it and cookies are sent with request to `js/app.js`. FireFox 58 (with `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` set to true) does not attach cookies. Even those not marked `HttpOnly`. Chrome doesn't send them if `use-credentials` is not specified.

As many web apps respond with 302 redirect to login page, typical reaction in the console is `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/js/app.js”.` or similar.

Of course, there are many ways to resolve it on the server side: allow JS modules to not require security checks, or place an auth token into the URL query. But it doesn't seem right.

What I am trying to understand, is there a definitive guide to the logic behind it? It used to be requests to the same origin, regardless of resource type, were carrying all cookies with them. Why would it be different for modules? Is there a magic attribute that makes it behave like the usual `<script type="text/javascript" src=...></script>` in regards to cookies?

Comment: Maybe it's just a bug/not yet implemented feature? Afaik, browser support for modules is still experimental

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi! It is indeed "in development" in FF, although this is the only issue I've seen, but it seems released and in full support in Chrome: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232 - yet, I still have to specify "crossorigin" (without actually doing CORS here). This is what I want to understand in the first place, why is it needed.

Comment: I remember there were issues with using credentials with preflight requests.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734031/why-does-the-preflight-options-request-of-an-authenticated-cors-request-work-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in FireFox 60.x.x - it attaches cookies correctly with `crossorigin="use-credentials"` attribute set, falling in line with other browsers, so, it must have been a bug. Also, `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` is true by default, so, it is safe to use modules with either: Chrome/Chromium, Firefox, Safari and Edge (16+) even if you check for session cookies on the server.

The logic behind including crossorigin="use-credentials" is similar to the one used by Fetch API and somewhat explained here [MDN CORS Settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes).

I guess using `type="module"` on the tag makes the browser either not use CORS at all with a result these requests are always anonymous and will have no security cookies. The only alternative is to follow CORS guidelines.